# Linking GCC static/shared libraries and threads and -fPIC flag

Tags: c++, gcc, pthreads

I'm building a shared library (C++ code using some C++11/14 features) which links to my own static library and uses threads.  It all uses CMake.  When I link my shared library ("gscore") and it tries to link to my static library ("gslicense"), I get and error regarding a symbol in pthreads.  Full text is further down but the short version is this:

> '__pthread_key_create' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

I've tried following the advice and added -fPIC to the compile-time flags for both of my projects.  I've verified that -fPIC is part of my compilation flags but the error persists.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Here is the error.

```
[ 57%] Linking CXX shared library libgscore.so
/usr/bin/ld: ../gslicense/libgslicense.a(gslicensing.cpp.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `__pthread_key_create' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
../gslicense/libgslicense.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
GSCore/CMakeFiles/gscore.dir/build.make:1014: recipe for target 'GSCore/libgscore.so' failed
make[2]: *** [GSCore/libgscore.so] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:173: recipe for target 'GSCore/CMakeFiles/gscore.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [GSCore/CMakeFiles/gscore.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

Here is how I added threading to my project in my CMakeLists.txt file

```
#
# pthread
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(gscore Threads::Threads)
```

This is all part of a port of a Windows codebase to linux using CMake.  I'm extremely familiar with Windows but fumble around in Linux.  I've tried searching all the threads I can find on SO but I'm still at a loss.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: What's missing is that anything that goes into a shared library must be compiled with `-fPIC`. If you link something with a static library, the modules from the static library get inserted into whatever you're linking it to. If you're linking a shared library, the modules from the static library go into the shared library. Therefore, the modules in your static library, because they go into the shared library, must be compiled with `-fPIC`.

Comment: Hi Sam,  Thanks for responding.  The thing is, I *am* compiling all files in the shared library with -fPIC.   I've examined the make file generated by CMAKE and I've build with VERBOSE.  That's why I can't understand why I'm still getting the error

Comment: @Joe But you did not compile the object file `gslicensing.cpp.o` which
is a member of `libgslicense.a` - namely `libgslicense.a(gslicensing.cpp.o)`
in the linker diagnostic - with `-fPIC`. And the linker needs to extract
that object file from `libgslicense.a` to link *it* into your shared
libary. `libgslicense.a` needs to be rebuilt from `-fPIC`-compiled
object files for linkage with any shared library.

Comment: What part of "the modules from the static library go into the shared library...therefore ... they must be compiled with `-fPIC`", as I wrote, you have a question about? Just because you used it with modules that go directly into the shared library, doesn't mean that modules that go there indirectly, via a static library, will do as well, automatically.

Comment: Sam and Mike.  You were both right.  I thought I was building with -fPIC but apparently I'm no better with CMake than I am with gcc.  I was trying to directly specify the CXX flag but apparently with CMake it works better if you just set POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE.  Thanks to both of you.  I'm slowly getting better at deciphering gcc output